# How often do you use your critical attack at the beginning?

Tags: bit-dungeon

I was wondering how often you use your critical attack in the beginning of bit dungeon, because I was playing the game the other day and noticed that the attack came at seemingly unorganized intervals.

Answer (score -1):

If you'll look at your stat list, you'll see you have a Magic Proc chance. When your Magic Proc triggers with no special magic, that is what causes the stunning pulse.

Comment: That is magic proc, not critical